# About using Burnside's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is the following.

> Consider a square toy made out of 4 balls on the corners connected by
>   4 symmetric pipes. How many distinct (up to rotation and flipping)
>   ways are there to make up this toy if we have 3 different colors
>   available for the balls?

I know that this is using Burnside's theorem to solve it.

(# of orbits)=$\frac {1}{|G|}$*$\sum_{x \in X} X_g$

$G=Z_4$, $|X|=3^4$

$\frac 14*(3^4+3+3+9)=24$

Am I right??

Thank you.

Comment: Just a note on naming: The result here is rarely called Burnside's theorem. It is commonly called Burnside's lemma, but since it is not originally due to Burnside, it is also sometimes called "The Lemma not due to Burnside".

Comment: As to the actual question, you have picked a too small group compared to the symmetries you have been told to consider. Apart from the rotations you consider, you also need to allow flips, so the group should be the dihedral group of order $8$.

Comment: So, $Z=D_4$ and $|X|=3^4$. Then $\frac 18$*$(3^4+3+3+9)$=12. Am I right?

Comment: Why are there still only $4$ summands in that? Have you taken some of the group elements simultaneously?

Comment: Actually, I can see that you have not, as the numbers would not be right. If you had only been asked to consider the rotations as symmetries, then your original answer would have been correct, so just do the same thing with the new group.

Comment: Ok. I didn't count the flipping..... Vertical flipping and horizontal flipping has both 9. And for diagonal flipping, flipping on / line has 27 ways and flipping on \ line has 27.
So, (# of orbits)=$\frac 1{|G|}$*$(3^4+3+9+3+9+9+27+27)$=$\frac {168}8=21$

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (it might be a good idea to try to find those $3$ that "disappear" by considering the extra symmetries compared to the original answer).